# Javascript return if found, otherwise set to undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my current solution

```
var snap = this.snaps.find((snap) => {
    if(pos > snap.min && snap.max > pos){
        return snap;
    }
})
if(snap !== undefined){
    this.scrollTo = snap.down ? snap.max : snap.min;
}else{
    this.scrollTo = undefined
}
```

I would like to achive the same thing but without the if else statement. I tried:

```
this.scrollTo = this.snaps.find((snap) => {
    if(pos > snap.min && snap.max > pos){
        return snap.down ? snap.max : snap.min;;
    }
})
```

but that does not work.

Comment: How are you using your second example to assign it to this.scrollTo?

Comment: Updated question, thanks!

Comment: @Himmators FYI, I saw your edit, but realized that your `var snap = ...` could be shortened significantly, so I edited my answer again.

Comment: Nice, that's a bit to compact for me, makes it harder to read, but that's a matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: @Himmators In that case, I recommend changing `return snap;` to `return true;` to make it obvious that it is the boolean of the value returned that matters for `find`. I believe you were thrown off by the `return snap;` since in your second snippet you modified that return statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `this.snaps.find` is [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), only the boolean value of whatever you return from the function matters. `return snap;` in that function has the the same effect as `return true;`. In your case it makes sense to return the boolean value of the condition instead of using an if statement. You can use an arrow function without curly braces to return the result of an expression without using `return`, so your `find` call can be shortened to:

```
var snap = this.snaps.find( snap => pos > snap.min && snap.max > pos );
```

You can use a logical `&&` operator to remove the other if/else. `&&` evaluates to its first operand if it is falsy (which `undefined` is), otherwise it evaluates to its second operand:

```
this.scrollTo = snap && (snap.down ? snap.max : snap.min);
```

Comment: Clean and easy solution. Perfect.